# LM2903 Comparator output oscillates

Tags: comparator

I am using an LM2903 Comparator on my design to measure sensor signal.  Constant current source is provided to the sensor by means of resistors (connected to 2.5V).  I have an RC input filter (R=1K,C=0.47u) at the non inverting input of the comparator followed by R1=1k (input resistor) and RF=475k (feedback resistor) for external hysteresis.  Reference voltage is 1.25V.
When I tested the circuit, I found my comparator output oscillates instead of saturating.  So I put small cap (10nF) across the feedback resistor.  Now the output bounces from high to low and vice versa even though my sensor input is constant.

Comment: I think you've got a circuit error, but maybe post a schematic.  Is there a resistor from inverting input to ground.. or your reference voltage?

Comment: Yes.1.25V is generated from 2.5VRef by means of voltage divider and given to inverting input.I don't know how to include my image file.

Comment: OK, What is the R value? (10k ohm? my fav. R) to slow down a comparator I think you want a C to ground on the output, not across the "hysterisis" resistor.  (my spelling stinks.)  I don't know the details of the LM2903.

Answer (score 1):

An LM2903 is an open collector device, you need a pull-up on the output.  Also, the LM2903 Vcc must account for headroom, so it probably needs at least 3.3V if not 5V power.